# Yum/Apt Package Repository Managament, Mirrors and Hosted, Must be something better

Tags: yum, apt, package-management, repository

I've been managing my Yum repositories with Pulp, mirrored and hosted.  The complexity is pretty serious, so I've only considered the operational and infrastructure related repositories.  DevOps has been almost completely off the table, as repository management has been too fragile to support across the enterprise.

So I've just had Jenkins upload RPMs with the mvn command to Nexus. I'm not happy with either work flow, the nexus not geared for this problem space, and Pulp has been too fragile to meet my needs.  I have been using Pulp, and I made it work despite the problems.

How do other teams mirror/host their packages, in a robust enterprise work-flow?. What about automation across teams?  A REST API of some sort?

Comment: First, we don't do product recommendations here. Second, this reads more like an angry rant than a coherent explanation of your problem(s).

Comment: I didn't ask for a recommendation, I wanted to know the ways other people handle their enterprise management of packages.  I will improve the question.

Comment: In additon the purpose of the question was to determine if I need to put a significant amount of engineering into a custom solution, or if this is a problem scope everyone has handled, and I can then make my own recommendation.

Comment: AFAIK pulp is the only currently maintained project in this space, and while I don't know why it doesn't support apt/deb, I do know the distributions which use those formats, and so I expect it is probably no accident. You can get commercial support for it via Red Hat, if you find that necessary, as it is part of their newest version of Satellite.